# Kentico 8.2 Newsletter Link and unsubscribe link

Tags: kentico, subscribe, unsubscribe

I have created a contact form under *Forms* with first name, last name, and email that is designed to sign up people for a newsletter.  I then created a page so when people click on the link placed on the home page it takes them to a page with the contact form.

Right now when I test the subscribe form out, the data does to to the "back office" where it can be retrieved. However, the information I entered is still in the text fields and, unless you notice the small flash of the web page, one might think nothing happened.

I'd like to know how (or be directed to somewhere in the Kentico 8.2 Documentation) I can make it so that the fields clear and a message appears saying "You have been subscribed to the newsletter."  That message can either appear on a separate page on the web site, or send a message to the user email, or both.  In the Email Marketing part under the templates there are Subscribe and Unsubscribe templates, but I don't know how to use those.

The other issue is creating an Unsubscribe link.  Ideally that will open up to a new page saying "You have been unsubscribed."  Kentico 8.2 has an unsubscribe page you can create where the user enters in an email address and then hits the Unsubscribe Request button, but I'd rather not do that.  As it stands, I did create a page with that form and tested it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit your form, under general tab, there are settings for what will happen after the form is submitted:

Display Text

Redirect to URL

Clear Form

Continue Editing.

Comment: I chose the Display Text option, saying "Thank you for subscribing to the newsletter." After submitting the info in the form as a test, the form disappears (which is fine), but no text appears with the message.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're using the standard Forms application for something which can be managed through the Newsletter/Email Campaign module.  [Read the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k82/on-line-marketing-features/email-marketing/working-with-email-campaigns/creating-static-campaign-emails) more on how to configure this vs. using the Forms application.

Essentially the steps you will do are:

1. Create your newsletter following the directions in the linked documentation.
2. Place a newsletter subscription webpart on your page template and configure it to the newsletter you want them to subscribe to.
3. Use the out of the box unsubscribe feature to allow users to unsubscribe to your newsletter.  No need to add any page to the content tree but you can if you want OR just use the OOTB functionality.

If you follow the documentation you should be able to get it setup properly vs. using an online form.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screen shot of what I should be seeing when I do these steps?

Comment: I should also mention that the Unsubscribe Link would be at the bottom of the Email Template.  I know it would not have to go into the content tree, but I'm not certain what URL it should link to.

Comment: There are screenshots in the provided documentation.  Take a walk through the documentation and come back with questions.  Regarding the unsubscribe URL, you can use the macro `{%UnsubscribeLink%}` and it will automatically generate the link for you based on out of the box setup or settings you configure in Kentico.